# Передача указателя на структуру

Tags: c, функции, указатели, struct

не могу передать указатель на структуру

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Print(qweptr strct){
    printf("%d\n", strct->data);
    return;
}

int main(void){
    SetConsoleCP (1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
    struct sh{
        int data;
    };
    typedef struct sh qwe; //qwe = struct sh
    typedef qwe* qweptr;// qweptr = qwe* = struct sh*
    qweptr start; // создаю struct sh *start
    if (!(start=(qweptr)malloc(1*sizeof(qwe)))){
        puts("Not enough memmory!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    start->data=10;
    Print(start);
return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение вашей структуры нужно расположить прежде чем будет объявлена функция Print, в которой используются указатели на эту структуру.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>

struct sh{ // перенёс эту штуку наверх
    int data;
};
typedef struct sh qwe; //qwe = struct sh
typedef qwe* qweptr; // qweptr = qwe* = struct sh*

void Print(qweptr strct){
    printf("%d\n", strct->data);
    return;
}

int main(void){
    //SetConsoleCP (1251);
    //SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
    qweptr start; // создаю struct sh *start
    if (!(start=(qweptr)malloc(1*sizeof(qwe)))){
        puts("Not enough memmory!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    start->data=10;
    Print(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, удивлен, что не додумался))